# ODE describing insect population

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The rate of increase of the population of insects is proportional to the number, , of insects present at any time  days after the beginning of the experiment. Given that the population of insects at the beginning is , and after 10 days is 2. Find in terms of ,
a) The population of insects after 5 days.
b) The days taken for the population of insects to be 3 times the original

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: does it need to use term of number, then use first ODE or continue to use first ODE?

Comment: The rate of increase of the population at a time $t$ is proportional to the population. at time $t$ What differential equation describes behaviors of this type?

Comment: I do not know what type it is. but this question under chapter application first ODE

Comment: Right, so then the only ODE you are likely to know at this point is the one that you should try to use. In particular, the most fundamental ODE is $y'=y$

Comment: okkk. can you show how to solve it?

Comment: i don't know how to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the derivative is the rate of change. The problem states that the rate of increase of the population is proportional to the population size. In a formula, this can be written as
\begin{equation}
P'(t) = kP(t).
\end{equation}
This equation has solution $P(t) = P_0 e^{kt}$. So we need to compute $k$. We know that $P_0 = S$, since $P(0)=S=P_0 e^{0}$. We also know $P(10) = S_2 = S  e^{10k}$. We can solve for $k$ and obtain $k = \frac{1}{10}\ln(\frac{S_2}{S}) = \ln((\frac{S_2}{S})^{\frac{1}{10}})$. From here it is smooth sailing.

Comment: yeah.... thank you for your explaination. now i get idea how to solve this question. Thanks @perpetuallyconfused